# Dashless GUID not used DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a page, which accepts a parameter x (which is a GUID).
On the page I have a

```
HTML.DropDownListFor(x => x.SomeGuidProperty).
```

If I specify parameter x in URL as `43f67d68-066d-4fda-94a8-3e3e4c7c278a` (with dashes), drop down selects respeced option.
But if I specify parameter x in URL as `43f67d68066d4fda94a83e3e4c7c278a` (still GUID, but no dashes) - DropDownList ignores it.

It is impossible to ensure single format of GUID, as page is used by different sources.

What can be done to make DropDownList understand parameter x?

Comment: The 2 values are not the same - how would you expect then to match?

Comment: Well, they both represent same GUID value. The model, passed to the view, has x as GUID property. And although it is passed as GUID (not as string) to DropDownList, it is completely ignored, if in URL x has no dashes (or has some other GUID format, which is not "D" format). Simple output of x, shows that it's value is really a GUID and is independant from x in URL.

Comment: how can you ensure the format a data posted as url? if it was a method parameter you could, but here you will need to check the presence of dashes and include when necessary

Comment: @Ricardo I have method in controller, which accepts x as GUID, puts x's value to model, and returns a view with the model supplied. Inside of the view I have a drop down list <-- and it makes a problem.

Comment: I got. Maybe can you accept parameter as string and convert to a Guid? It will receive everything, and you can check for dashes before convert.

Comment: It will not change anything because I already have it as GUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding directly to a `Guid`, you'll need to bind to a string and then programmatically convert to a `Guid`. For example, instead of something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo(Guid x)
```

You'll need:

```
public Actionresult Foo(string x)
```

Then inside, you'll want to format `x` as a `Guid` should be formatted, if it's not already before converting it to an actual `Guid`: `var guid = new Guid(x)`.